# How to animate the world scene to affect selected object

Tags: animation, world

I have set up a scene, and I have animated the world position spinning, but its affecting both of the cubes. How can I make the world target only one cube, so the other one doesn't get the reflections from the rotating/animating world scene?

[image]

Comment: maybe do it in two steps, first one cube, with a transparent background, then the other one, with the rotating world scene, then combine in the video sequencer?